# Как удалить из первого списка все элементы второго списка?

Tags: java, list

Например у меня есть:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList first = new LinkedList();  // first = ['A', 'B', 'B', 'A']
    LinkedList second = new LinkedList();  // second = ['B', 'A']
  }
}
```

Мне нужно удалить все элементы из первого списка, которые есть во втором. В конце должно получиться:

*first = ['A', 'B'], 

second = [] **или** second = ['B', 'A']*

Но при этом желательно не использовать цикл. Это возможно сделать или я слишком много прошу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пройтись в цикле и удалить встреченные элементы:

```
LinkedList first = new LinkedList();  // first = ['A', 'B', 'B', 'A']
first.addAll(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "B", "A"));

LinkedList second = new LinkedList();  // second = ['B', 'A']
second.addAll(Arrays.asList("B", "A"));

for (Object o : second) {
    first.remove(o);
}
System.out.println(first);  // [B, A]
```

Вместо цикла можно использовать конструкцию из streams-api (@Russtam, спс за подсказку):

```
second.forEach(first::removeFirstOccurrence);
System.out.println(first);  // [B, A]
```

---

Сначала будет удалена первая попавшаяся `B` (`['A', 'B', 'A']`), после `A` (`['B', 'A']`)

Comment: second.forEach(first::removeFirstOccurrence);

Comment: @Russtam, stream-api просто божественный :)

Answer (score 0):

```
int index = Collections.indexOfSubList(first, second);
    if (index!=-1) {
        List<String> list1 = first.subList(0, index);
        List<String> list2 = first.subList(index + second.size(), first.size());
        list1.addAll(list2);
        first = list1;
    }
```